# Better Method to Store Aliases?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, alias

I added a list of aliases in my `~/.bash_profile`

Now loading a new terminal window takes an unacceptable amount of time ~10s.

Is there a better way or location to store aliases for daily use?

Here are examples of some of the common ones I use:

`alias sshcol="kubectl exec -ti $(kubectl get pod --selector=app=collector --field-selector=status.phase=Running -n etl -o jsonpath={.items[0].metadata.name}) -n etl -c collector /bin/bash"`

`alias logscol="kubectl logs --tail=50 $(kubectl get pod --selector=app=collector --field-selector=status.phase=Running -n etl -o jsonpath={.items[0].metadata.name}) -n etl -c collector"`

Comment: `$(kubectl get pod` - it's because you run this command each time.

Comment: Since you are running `kubectl get pod` when you *define* the alias, not when you *use* it, you can probably run it one time and re-use the value in each definition.

Comment: If that's actually a bug and you *do* need to run `kubctl get pod` each time you use the alias, you need to escape the `$` or use single quotes. Either way, alias definition will speed up.

Answer (score 2):

`$(kubectl get pod` - it's because you run the command inside `$(...)` each time the bash_profile is sourced. You could use a function.

```
sshcol() {
    kubectl exec -ti "$(kubectl get pod --selector=app=collector --field-selector=status.phase=Running -n etl -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")" -n etl -c collector /bin/bash
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be re-running `kubectl get pod` more than necessary. For example,

```
# Run this once and save the result
pod=$(kubectl get pod --selector=app=collector --field-selector=status.phase=Running -n etl -o jsonpath={.items[0].metadata.name})

alias sshcol="kubectl exec -ti \"$pod\" -n etl -c collector /bin/bash"
alias logscol="kubectl logs --tail=50 \"$pod\" -n etl -c collector"
```

You might want to use functions in place of aliases.

If, however, it is a bug that `kubectl get pod` is running at definition time and it really needs to run when you use the alias, you should *definitiely* define a function as in [Kamil Cuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57435990/1126841).

Comment: Couldn't you just single quote the whole thing and it only gets evaluated when the alias is used?

Comment: You could, but 1) I already suspect the repeated call is unnecessary and 2) at that point, I would prefer a function definition anyway. I alluded to single quotes in my original comment to the question.